# How to count ids across two distinct columns in SQL

Tags: sql, graph, presto

I have a table that contains two different columns called: `a_id` and `b_id`.

I want to process these two columns and count the distinct number of job ids in each column and report that. Ultimately, I want to determine how many total jobs were created on any given day and how many jobs were completed on any given day.

I started writing up a rough query to attempt to solve this issue but realized that the select distinct is more complicated than I thought. I also am producing one column: called `total_jobs` and I think there should be two columns: `total jobs created` and `total jobs completed` based on `job_created_date` and `job_completed_date`. Kind of lost here.

```
SELECT
job_created_date,
job_completed_date,
category,
   COUNT(
        SELECT 
        DISTINCT a_id, b_id
        FROM my_data_table
    ) AS total_jobs

FROM my_data_table
WHERE
    ds BETWEEN '<DATEID-8>' AND '<DATEID-1>'
GROUP BY
    1, 2, 3, 4
```

I want the output to help me create a bar graph with dates on the x-axis and stacked bars representing # of jobs created on that day and # of jobs remaining to be completed on that day.

Comment: How do you know if a job is completed?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: First, tag the appropriate database name. Now, if you add both created and finished date to the GROUP BY, this will return some meaningless data for you. Finally, please add some sample data with your expected out which will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't' know what your data looks like, but I can speculate that you have one row per job and `job_completed_date` is non-`NULL` for completed jobs.

If so, you can do:

```
SELECT t.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER () as total_jobs,
       COUNT(job_complete) as total_completed_jobs
FROM my_data_table t
WHERE t.ds BETWEEN '<DATEID-8>' AND '<DATEID-1>';
```